# get include_player_ids params values for POST request in Postman

Tags: android, http-post, postman, onesignal

I'm working on Remote Notifications in my Ionic App using OneSignal.

I have created an App in OneSignal, configured it for my app and initiated the service as per the Official Docs.

To test this, I am using Postman Chrome Extension. So, after adding the **POST Request URL**, where can I find the String values for the ***include_player_ids*** key.

I have my app still in testing state.

What's the code in `typescript` to get the value of ***include_player_ids*** from our Mobile Device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
            console.log('getIds: ' , ids);
            self.deviceToken    =   ids.pushToken;
            self.userId         =   ids.userId;
            console.log(self.userId);
        });
```

That gives u `deviceToken` and `OneSignal User ID`, which is referred to as `Player ID`

I copied the value from the console and used!

Thanks @Saiy2k

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the OneSignal Native Android SDK, you should use the OneSignal [idsAvailable](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-api#IdsAvailable) method to get the device's OneSignal Player Id and then pass this value to your server.